# Why QImage doesn't display real size image?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qimage

I have the following code :

```
QImage mypic(100, 100, QImage::Format_RGB32);
mylabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(mypic));
```

which display an image.

The problem is that, analyzing mouse coordinates, I could see the size of image displayed is 82x82, not 100x100.

Why it's not the size I specified and how can I correct ?

Comment: What is the size set to mylabel; is it large enough to display the full image?

Comment: Have you set 'scaledContent' property in the label ?

Comment: How do you "analyze mouse coordinates"?

Comment: @Merlin069, I didn't set a size to mylabel.

Comment: @rmi, no I didn't set 'scaledContent' to the label.

Comment: Perhaps that's the problem, the label is scaling down the image because it's not large enough.

Comment: @Merlin069. So you think I have to set a size of 200x200 to my label ?

Comment: Have you tried that? Also note that there's a setScaledContents function on QLabel. Try setting that to false. If the label's too small, the pixmap will be cropped to its size.